# How to access query return value in model (CodeIgniter) using Smarty?

Tags: php, codeigniter, smarty

I am studying smarty with codeigniter. I don't know how to access the query returned value from my model.

Here's my code.

My model

```
class User_Model extends CI_Model{

        public function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public function getAllCategory(){

            $query = "SELECT * FROM sales_category";
            $result = $this->db->query($query);
            return $result;

        }

    }
```

My Controller

```
class User_Controller extends CI_Controller{

        public function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public function index(){
            $category = $this->user_model->getAllCategory();
            $this->smartylib->assign('category',$category);
            $this->smartylib->assign('title','Hello World');
            $this->smartylib->display('index.tpl');
        }

    }
```

My template file

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{$title}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {assign var=x value=''}
        {foreach $category->result_array() as $x}
            {$x['salesscatname']}
        {/foreach}
    </body>
</html>
```

That's all guys I hope you can help me. Thanks.

Comment: Try in your controler $this->smartylib->assign('category',$category->result_array()); and in template foreach ($category as $x)

Comment: Ok thanks. Sorry for the question. I really don't have an idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $this->user_model->getAllCategory();
```